# NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator in MapPartitionsToPair-Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to do a `MapPartitionsToPair` in Spark Streaming, but it always returns the error: NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator.

Here is my code:

```
 JavaPairDStream<String,String> streamGiveKey=   streamData1.mapPartitionsToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<Iterator<String>, String, String>() {
      @Override
      public Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>> call(Iterator<String> stringIterator) throws Exception {

            ArrayList<Tuple2<String,String>>arrayOfPartitionsWithKeys= new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, String>>();

             while (stringIterator.hasNext()){
                 if(stringIterator.next()==null){
                     return null;
                 }

                 JsonMessage retMap = new Gson().fromJson(stringIterator.next(),JsonMessage.class);
                 String key= retMap.getSid();
                Tuple2<String,String> keyValue= new Tuple2<String,String>(key,stringIterator.next());
                 arrayOfPartitionsWithKeys.add(keyValue);

             }


 return  arrayOfPartitionsWithKeys;
         }
    });
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you call iterator.next() you move one element forward in the underlying collection. In this case I suggest to use next once in your loop and assign it to a local var and reuse that var...

Comment: Fantastic, worked like a charm! :) Thank you very much.